# Xcode 6 Swift WebThread crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, exc-bad-access

I am using Xcode 6 with Swift to display PDF file through UIWebView in an iOS app as follow:

```
@IBOutlet weak var displayWebView: UIWebView!

func displayView(viewfile: NSData){
    displayWebView.loadData(viewfile, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: nil)
}
```

The viewfile is a NSData comes from segue in a previous screen which is a tableview.

The display of PDF works normally. But when the app go back and forth to and from the previous screen, the app crashes in the 'loadData' step with "WebThread (xx): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)" message as below:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
    0x106da3000 <+0>:   testq  %rdi, %rdi
    0x106da3003 <+3>:   jle    0x106da3068               ; <+104>
    0x106da3005 <+5>:   movq   (%rdi), %r11
    0x106da3008 <+8>:   movq   %rsi, %r10
->  0x106da300b <+11>:  andl   0x18(%r11), %r10d    WebThread (24): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    0x106da300f <+15>:  shlq   $0x4, %r10
    0x106da3013 <+19>:  addq   0x10(%r11), %r10
    0x106da3017 <+23>:  cmpq   (%r10), %rsi
```

Sometimes, the error is:

```
WebKitLegacy`-[WebDataSource(WebPrivate) dataSourceDelegate]:
    0x10c51dbb0 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x10c51dbb1 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10c51dbb4 <+4>:  movq   0x11ad95(%rip), %rax      ; WebDataSource._private
    0x10c51dbbb <+11>: movq   (%rdi,%rax), %rax
->  0x10c51dbbf <+15>: movq   0x18(%rax), %rax     WebThread (17): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    0x10c51dbc3 <+19>: popq   %rbp
    0x10c51dbc4 <+20>: retq   
    0x10c51dbc5 <+21>: nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

These crashes happen no matter target at iOS 8 and iOS 7 and the place of breakdown looks random. Although there are similar posts on similar symptoms, they are Objective-C solution instead of Swift.

Would someone inform the solution of problem in Swift?

Comment: see if the code is executing from the main thread and if not, make it execute from that thread, just in case.

Comment: the code is not executing from main thread from from a block in getDataInBackgroundWithBlock to get data from parse.com and then execute loaddata in the block to make sure the data is extracted before display. If execute loaddata from main thread, it does not know the block has finished. In these situation, how can I know (in the main thread) a getDataInBackgroundWithBlock has finished and then execute loaddata?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you update the view after calling "loadData"? the execution within the block is still synchronous relative to its thread.

`[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            //handle error
        }
        else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self loadData];
                [self updateView];
            });
        }
    }];`